# Is there a way to import data (csv data) to the winlogbeat kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I had just started learning about ElasticSearch and Kibana. I created a Winlogbeat dashboard where the logs are working fine. I want to import additional data (CSV data) which I created using Python. I tried uploading the CSV file but I am only allowed to create a separate index and not merge it with the Winlogbeat data. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many use cases, you don't need to actually combine into a single index. Here's a few ways you can show combined data, in approximate order of complexity:

Straightforward methods, using separate indices:

- Use multiple charts on a dashboard
- Use multiple indices in a single chart

More complex methods that combine data into a single index:

- Pivot indices using Data Transforms
- Combine at ingest-time
- Roll your own

### Use multiple charts on a dashboard

This is the simplest way: ingest your data into separate indices, make separate visualizations for them, then add those visualisations to one dashboard. If the events are time-based, this simple approach could be all you need.

### Use multiple indices in a single chart

Lens, TSVB and Timelion can all use multiple data sources. (Vega can too, but that's playing on hard mode)

Here's an official Elastic video about how to do it in Lens: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDPMrX7Lvmg)

### Create pivot indices using Data Transforms

You can use Elasticsearch's [Data Transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/transforms.html) functionality to fetch, combine and aggregate your disparate data sources into a combined data structure which is then available for querying with Kibana. The official tutorial on [Transforming the eCommerce sample data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/ecommerce-transforms.html) is a good place to learn more.

### Combine at ingest-time

If you have (or can add) Logstash in the mix, you have several options for combining datasets during the `filter` phase of your pipelines:

- Using a file-based lookup table and the [translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter plugin
- By waiting for related documents to come in then outputting a combined document to Elasticsearch with the [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter plugin
- Using external lookups with filter plugins like [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) or [http](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html)
- Executing arbitrary ruby code using the [ruby](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.htmll) filter plugin

### Roll your own

If you're generating the CSV file with a Python program, you might want to think about incorporating the python [Elasticsearch DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib to run queries on the winlogbeat data, then ingest it in its combined state (whether via a CSV or other means).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Winlogbeat is a data shipper to Elasticsearch. Which ships windows specific data to an index named `winlogbeat` with a specific schema and document structure.

You can't merge another document with a [different schema](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/exported-fields.html) into `winlogbeat` index.

If your goal is to correlate different data points. Please use [Time-series visual builder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/time-series-visual-builder.html) to overlay two different datasets to visualize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense.